# Mongodb command failure exception

Tags: java, mongodb

I am seeing this error when I try to write data to mongodb.

> com.mongodb.commandFailureException: err msg: Bson field
> ‘authenticate.nonce’ is an unknown field. Code 40415

```
public void writeToMongo(BasicDBObject data){
    MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createMongoCRCredential(username, dbName, pwd);
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(hostIp,port, Arrays.asList(credential)));
    database= client.getDB(dbName);
    collection= database.getCollection(“nameTable”);
    collection.save(data);
}
```

Anyone could help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB 40415: BSON field 'create.bsonType' is an unknown field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59660010/mongodb-40415-bson-field-create-bsontype-is-an-unknown-field)

Comment: @Thomas hello there!! I hope so but the error message is different.

Comment: Yeah, because it's a field from the validator defined in _your_ database.

Comment: What is the version of Java driver you are using?

Comment: @Thomas what is a validator?

Comment: `new MongoClient(..` - this is legacy version of using the `MongoClient`. Looks like the `new ServerAddress(` doesn't have the third param `Arrays.asList(credential)`. Does your code compile?